# How could I identify peers of companies (stocks) at scale?

Tags: data, market-data

**Context:**

I'm making a small script to screen through thousands of companies at scale. A feature that I want to include would be relative metrics, e.g. is this company growing faster than its peers, has better margins, and so on.

I can find the sector and industry in various databases, but it's not always very accurate. For example on Yahoo Finance:

- MSFT: Technology, Software—Infrastructure
- AAPL: Technology, Consumer Electronics
- GOOG: Communication Services, Internet Content & Information
- FB: Communication Services, Internet Content & Information
- AMZN: Consumer Cyclical, Internet Retail

While these classifications are true, I'd probably group these companies together.

Google autocomplete would often match my intuition better. For example, it gives me:

- MSFT vs Apple
- GOOG vs Microsoft

**Question:**

How can I identify peers of companies at scale?
For example:

- Does some database for this exist?
- Can I get google autocompletes at scale and map these somehow easily to companies?
- Or is there some other clever way to find these?

Comment: "How can I identify peers of companies at scale?" - clustering?

Comment: What would you use as the main features for such clustering?

Comment: You mentioned in your original post, "relative metrics, e.g. is this company growing faster than its peers, has better margins, and so on", so presumably you have some in mind..? This is not a new idea, see for e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-analysis-on-stock-selection-2c2fd079b295

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what “at scale” means, but it sound like GIC or SIC code is what you’re looking for. I think GIC is proprietary since it’s from MSCI, but SIC can be found on the EDGAR database.

https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/siccodes.htm

Edit:
To be clearer, using SIC codes gives you the flexibility to construct your own industries. Check out the Kenneth R. French data library as an example. The 12 industry portfolio groups GOOG, AAPL, and MSFT under “BusEq”. That is why I think SIC codes are what you’re looking for. It starts with using the SEC/EDGAR database as a resource.

Comment: My impression was the OP disagrees with the standard industry classifications ("I can find the sector and industry in various databases, but it's not always very accurate") hence the question.

Comment: Yes, the question was how to scrape "People Also Watch" section on Yahoo Finance.